# createViewModel from 'mobx-utils' gives undesired behavior of dirty state

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react, mobx-utils

The `createViewModel` dirty state does not work properly. On assigning the `address` property to some other address, `createViewModel` rightly judge the dirty value to be `true` however when I revert to the old value `createViewModel` still shows dirty as `true`, which is wrong.

I have also explicitly assigned address property as `observable.struct` so that real property gets compared and not the references.

Can someone please help, have been stuck with this problem for hours. I'm using `mobx@6.10.0` and `mobx-utils@6.0.8` versions.

**Code Sandbox Link:**
https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/createviewmodel-64z5qz?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.mjs%3A28%2C70

```
const { autorun, action, observable } = require("mobx");
const { createViewModel } = require("mobx-utils");

function Todo() {
  const person = observable({ name: 'tarun', address: { firstLine: 'this is the main address', secondLine: 'second thing' } }, { address: observable.struct });

  const personViewModel = createViewModel(person);

  autorun(() => {
    console.log('personViewModel?.address.firstLine', personViewModel?.address.firstLine);
    console.log('personViewModel?.address.secondLine', personViewModel?.address.secondLine)

    console.log('personViewModel.isDirty', personViewModel?.isDirty)
  })

  const update = action((address) => {
    personViewModel.address = address;
  })

  return {
    update
  }
}

const { update } = Todo();

// isDirty becomes true which is correct
update({ firstLine: 'edit first 1', secondLine: 'edit second 1' });

// when the address is reset 'isDirty' still shows true
update({ firstLine: 'this is the main address', secondLine: 'second thing' })
```